# Simple way to go through an async cursor in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cursor

I want to write the last amount of code possible to go through an async cursor.
I started off with the following (broken) code:

```
function something( done ){

  stores.someStore.select( {}, { cursor: true }, function( err, cursor ){

    var processItem = function( err, item ){

      console.log("Item before check:", item );
      if( item === null ) return;

      console.log("Item:", item );
      cursor.next( processItem);
    };

    cursor.next( processItem );
  });
}
```

This is obviously very broken:

- Doesn't check err
- I cannot make things happen within `goThroughCursor` once the cursor is finished

I came up with this solution, which just seems so over-complicated, that there *must* be a better way to do it...

```
function goThroughCursor( cursor, processItem, cb ){

  function f(){

    cursor.next( function( err, item ){

      if( err ) return cb( err );
      if( item === null ) return cb( null );

      processItem( item, function( err ){
        if( err ) return cb( err );

        f();
      });
    });
  }
  f();
};


function something( done ){

  stores.someStore.select( {}, { cursor: true }, function( err, cursor ){
    if( err ) return done( err );

    var processItem = function( item, cb ){
      console.log("Item is: ", item ); 
      cb( null );
    }

    goThroughCursor( cursor, processItem, function( err ){
      if( err ) return done( err );

      console.log("Cursor done!");
    });
  });
}
```

So, basicaly `goThroughCursor()` is a generic function that will call `next()` to a cursor and will stop when it comes back as `null`. For each valid item, it will run `processItem()`

I then simply use that function, passing it the `cursor` and the `processItem()` function.

Is this way too complicated?

With async, I would do this (which is STILL quite verbose):

```
function something( done ){

  stores.someStore.select( {}, { cursor: true }, function( err, cursor ){
    if( err ) return done( err );

    var item;
    async.doWhilst(
      function( callback ){
        cursor.next( function( err, i ){
          if( err ) return callback( err );

          item = i;
          if( item !== null ){
            console.log( "ITEM IS:", item );
          }

          callback( null );
        });
      },

      function(){ return item != null; },

      function( err ) {
        if( err ) return done( err );

        console.log( "ALL DONE!" );
        done( null );
      }
    );

  })
}
```

However, even the async solution is way too long. Surely, this MUST be a common problem for developers... what am I missing?

Comment: I don't think your implementation is too complicated. Will you need a "final" single output after processing all elements? If so, it seems that you are trying to implement a "reduce" or "fold" function.

Comment: Maybe my code is not as bad as I felt it was :D The point of the "final" output is so that my program can continue once the cursor has been read...